# I have problems with "removing" part of my code, not working as intended

Tags: c, cs50

I have problems with "removing" part of my code, not working as intended(TASK: make all caps, remove all nonletter). I am going through CS50, Harvard online course, in their IDE.

Ex:

```
Input:nhfdjnhjsldkfnlksdaj      JKLNKJBLKL:KJ    !@#$%^&&*)_()+_~
Output: NHFDJNHJSLDKFNLKSDAJ     JJKLNKJBLKLKKJ   !@#$%^&&*)_()+_~
```

Code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(word1);i++)
    {
        if(word1[i]>='a'&&word1[i]<='z')
        {
         // change to uppercase
         word1[i]=toupper(word1[i]);

        }
        else if(word1[i]<'A' || (word1[i]>'Z' && word1[i]<'a') ||word1[i]>'z')
        {
            //Remove
            word1[i]=word1[i+1];
            
        }
        else
        {
            //just add, upper alredy
            word1[i]=word1[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", word1);
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable, and we don't provide tutoring services here.  Ask your teacher, TA or learning center for assistance.

Comment: This is not how you remove the i'th letter: `word1[i]=word1[i+1]`. What this actually does is overwrite the i'th letter with the (I+1)'th letter but leaves all other letters the same (so your string remains the same length and you've simply duplicated certain letters). You can see this easily if you debug your code or print out word1 before and after that statement.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. Could you give me a hint or tell me how to do it. I tried a lot of different approaches but they all have failed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would be happy to but it will take forever due to the fact that I live in different time zone and this course is online

Comment: It's easier if you copy to a new string rather than trying to do it in place. Is the latter a requirement?

Comment: Use this search to find previous questions about removing characters: `[c] remove character from string`

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have the task of transforming a terminated string in C in-place by sequentially walking it and "removing" characters that match a specific criteria, you can do it with a "reader" and a "writer". The reader dictates where the next character comes from, the writer dictates where the next character to be stored is written.

The basic pattern for doing is shown below. I've used pointers to do this, but it can just as easily be done with array indexing; the concept is the same:

```
// initially both reader and writer at the string beginning
char *wr = word1;
for (const char *rd = word1; *rd; ++rd)
{
    // some condition that determines whether to keep the read-char
    if (condition to keep *rd here)
    {
        // save current read-char at the current 
        //  write pos and advance writer.
        *wr++ = *rd; 
    }
}
*wr = 0; // terminate the string
```

Note the reader always advances with each iteration; the writer only advances when we conclude we want to keep the current read-char. Once the loop is complete the writer will be pointing to where the string terminator should be placed (which could be the original string terminator position if we decided to keep everything)

It should be fairly obvious that if the entire string is filled with to-be-kept data this algorithms does a fair amount of work for ultimately no gain. But the moment even one character in the sequence is excluded, managing separate reader and writer positions becomes critical.

An example of how this works, to keep all alphabetic characters (whether upper or lower case makes no difference), you could do this:

```
char *wr = word1;
for (const char *rd = word1; *rd; ++rd)
{
    if (isalpha((unsigned char)*rd))
        *wr++ = *rd;
}
*wr = 0;
```

This can be extended to transform the data being retained. The above needs only one modification converting the to-be-kept character to upper case when committing to the writer location to accomplish your assignment. I leave you that task.

Finally, this general algorithm is reasonable only when the string being processed is potentially excluding content. If the goal is to *expand* content (ex: for each upper-case character repeat the char once, so AbCd becomes AAbCCd) this algorithm will not work.